# Algorithm to detect duplication of integers in an unsorted array of n integers. (implemented with 2 nested loops)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, nested-loops

**You are given an unsorted array of n integers, and you would like to find if there are any duplicates in the array (i.e. any integer appearing more than once).
Describe an algorithm (implemented with two nested loops) to do this.**

My description of the algorithm:

In step 1, we write a while loop to check to see if the array is empty/null, if the array is not null then we proceed with an inner loop.
Step 2, we now write a for loop to run an iteration of n-1 and in that loop we will assign to current (variable) the first index in the array (in the first iteration) and we will update the current variable by index + 1 each time through the iteration which means that the first time, current will hold the first index in the array and the second time, it will hold the second index in the array and so on until the loop ends.
Step 3, we will write a loop within the for loop (used in step 2) to compare the current number to all the integers in the array, if the integer equals to the next number then we will print the number using a printf statement else update next to hold the next index in the array  and use that to compare to the current variable and do so until it has been compared to all the integers in the array and once this has been done, the current variable will be updated to store the next index of the array and will compare that particular number to all the integers in the array.

Will the algorithm be correct? (according to the question)... you're suggestions would be grateful. And no! it's not a homework question or such. Thank you for your time.

The complexity is definitely **O (N^2) = N * ((N + 1)/2)** Or ***O(N^2)*** in its simplified manner.

Edit:
I have added a description of an algorithm that is more efficient (in the question below). But going back to the question above, would it be suitable as an answer for an exam question? (it has shown up in previous papers so i would really appreciate your help).

**If we limit the input data in order to achieve some best case scenario, how can you limit the input data to achieve a better Big O complexity? Describe an algorithm for handling this limited data to find if there are any duplicates. What is the Big O complexity?**

If we limit the data to, let’s say, array size of 5 (n = 5), we could reduce the complexity to O(N).   If the array is sorted, than all we need is a single loop to compare each element to the next element in the array and this will find if duplicates exist.   Which simply means that if an array given to us is by default (or luckily) already sorted (from lowest to highest value) in this case the reduction will be from O(N^2) to O(N) as we wouldn’t need the inner loop for comparing the integers for sorting since it is already sorted therefore we could implement a single loop to compare the integers to its successor and if a duplicate is encountered, then we could, for instance, use a printf statement to print the duplicates and proceed to iterate the loop n-1 times (which would be 4)- ending the program once that has been done.   The best case in this algorithm would be O(N) simply because the performance grows linearly and in direct proportion to the size of the input/ data so if we have a sorted array of size 50 (50 integers in the array) then the iteration would be n-1 (the loop will iterate 50 – 1 times) where n is the length of the array which is 50.   The running time in this algorithm increases in direct proportion to the input size. This simply means that in a sorted array, the amount of time the operations take to perform is completely dependent on the input size of the array.

p.s. Sure there are other algorithms efficient and faster but from my knowledge and from what the question asks is for a better big o complexity in the first question and i believe this algorithm achieves that. (correct me if i'm wrong)- thanks :)

Comment: This sounds like an interview question I've heard before. Isn't the range well defined? Maybe you can avoid using the trivial solution thinking about your data and limits.

Comment: @Spidey actually it's just a previous exam paper question that i am currently attempting. I've limited the data and applied an efficient algorithm- shown under the edit part in my post.

Comment: Please dont remove question

Comment: if you know the range (is not too big) then use histogram for loop. and then you know exactly what number is duplicate so you can remove it ... no nested loops necessary all runs on O(N) for big ranges use dynamic list for histogram + binary search to preserve memory but it will cost you ... O(N*log(M)) where N is input array size and M is input array values range size (in distinct items)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You describe three loops, but the first is actually just a condition (If is null or empty abort).

The remaining algo sounds good, except I'd say instead of "current will hold the first index in the array" (which nitpicks would insist is always 0 in C) "current will hold value of first element in the array" or such.

As an aside (although I understand it's a practice assignment) it's so terribly inefficient (I think n^2 is correct). I urge to just have one loop over the array, copying the checked numbers in a sorted structure of some kind and do binary searches in it. (As a teacher I'd have my students describe a balanced tree first so that they can use it here, like a virtual library ;-) ).

Comment: Perhaps the idea is to get them to learn the bad way now, so they can contrast it with a better way later?

Comment: A little optimization would be to have the second loop not over "all elements" but only over the remaining ones since dups with preceding elements would have been detected there. (The OP's (N+1)/2 seems to indicate that idea , but why +1?). That would also solve the OP's additional question.

Comment: @MarkRansom you're spot on! the following question asks us to modify the algorithm to represent the 'best' case, not 'worst' (which would be the usual case). I've approached the data to be sorted by default (when handed to us) and limited the data to, lets say 5. this would give us a reduction of O(N^2) to O(N) in an already sorted array. we now only require a single loop to check for duplications (e.g if current == next- duplicate found) else iterate outer loop and update current to store the next element in the array and compare to the current+1 element. iterates n-1 times (n=5 in this case)

Comment: @PeterSchneider Sorry for my lack of knowledge of loop types but could you please provide a loop that i could implement instead of 'While' because as you have stated, it's a condition. The question asks for 2 nested loops therefore my algorithm would have 2 nested loops as the outer loop is a condition. Could you implement a loop what wouldn't effect the big O complexity and one that achieves the task of my while loop. Thanks

Comment: Could that be a misunderstanding? "Two nested loops" may be just two loops; one is inside the other, just 1 nesting level, e.g. foreach(){ foreach() {...} }